# If I work on my own web server,nobody can track me,right?

Tags: linux, networking, home-networking, webserver, linux-server

I would like to make my own home web server with a Linux-based server operating system,I'm not sure what operating system I should choose,but I will see... After I make it,I will be able to do whatever I want on it without being banned or catched or other people like my cable/internet operator will be able to see what I'm doing?

P.S:I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: No, that's not how it works.

Comment: Nobody can track what? Server is just a computer, it still has to communicate through the Internet the same way regular PCs do. (Unless you use [avian carriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers).)

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? There are a pretty good number of options to *minimize* tracking but nothing that will be 100% secure against a determined adversary short of avoiding computers altogether.

Answer (score 1):

To make a private computer network all you need is an Ethernet hub/switch.  Plug all your devices into the hub -- no connection to the outside world.  (You will have to manually assign IP addresses.)  If you want wireless Ethernet you can use a standard WiFi router, just don't attach anything to the "outside world" connection (and, of course, to keep it private, *secure* the router using strong encryption).  (The router should then assign IP addresses for you, but generally won't provide DNS, so you may still want to do manual IP assignment.)

You can also place your server on a standard home network, if you don't want the network totally isolated.  Other boxes at home will be able to reach the server, and if your network router is secure then the outside world will not be able to reach the server (unless you want that).

There are other variations where you use two Ethernet adapters per computer, but that gets complicated.

If you want your server to be able to "serve" the outside world it requires a router capable of letting your server be "seen" externally, and your Internet provider may detect the server and require you to get a commercial account (ie, more $$).

Answer (score 0):

[update: *I see this is only answering the part "nobody can track me", 
but ignoring "setup a network"*]

Yes, if you run your own web server and your web browser at home,
and also connect from the browser to the server via your local network only,
nobody can interfere with your work. If you want to be sure that nobody is breaking into your home network, you could also disconnect from the internet, as you do not really need it, theoretically.

(You can use any Linux you want as the server, for example Ubuntu)

Comment: You tell him to disconnect Internet and make a LAN consisting of single web server and single client? How is that better than a single PC without Internet connection?

Comment: I think what he is trying to do is to set up some kind of small, local "real network", to learn or to experiment. Otherwise it makes not much sense to run that local web server in the first place I think. @VIPaul, is that right?

Comment: And, when not being tracked is important, not being connected is a very valid approach. Not sure I really understand the point of the OP though.

Comment: Yes,I just wanna gain some experience at this moment...